# Cause: duplicate entry: AndroidManifest.xml- What seems to be the issue?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I also have the same issue with the `AndroidManifest` file.

The "Merged Manifest" tab shows this **error**

```
Merging Errors: Warning provider#com.telhum.chat.utils.MyFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:75 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present DreamsChat.app main manifest (this file), line 74
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.telhum.chat">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

        <application
            android:name="com.telhum.chat.BaseApplication"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo_"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:appComponentFactory">

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.ChatActivity"
                android:parentActivityName="com.telhum.chat.activities.MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

                <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan">-->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.telhum.chat.activities.MainActivity" />
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.ImageViewerActivity" />

            <service
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.services.FirebaseChatService"
                android:enabled="true" />
            <service android:name="com.telhum.chat.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

            <receiver
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.receivers.ConnectivityReceiver"
                android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <!-- https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyCkFC_Ev5SLOfJPto9NG0BJnlwOwxwc5Z0" />

            <provider
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.utils.MyFileProvider"
                android:authorities="@string/authority"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                tools:replace="android:authorities">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
            </provider>

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.ContactViewerActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.ChatDetailActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.SignInActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.CallScreenActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.IncomingCallScreenActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.SplashActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.services.FetchMyUsersService"
                android:exported="false" />
            <service
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.services.SinchService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.ChooseSignInActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_sign_in"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.ContactActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.status.glideProgressBar.OkHttpProgressGlideModule"
                android:value="GlideModule" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.StatusStoriesActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/FullScreenVideoTheme" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.telhum.chat.activities.CallListActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" />

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Try to remove this line `tools:replace="android:authorities"`

Comment: Thanks @luca_999 , but Im still getting the error even after removing the line.

Comment: What is the value of `@string/authority`?

Comment: Are you referring to this??  <string name="authority">com.telhum.chat.fileprovider</string>